# How to model a price discount with a purchase of several products as condition?

Tags: database-design

### Scenario

Let us say that, in my business context, there are three different *products*, i.e., product `one`, `two` and `three`, and I wish to offer *price discounts* when a condition like the following one takes place:

- If a *customer* buys 2 units of product `one` and 1 unit of product `two`, I will give him a *price discount* of `x`% on product `three`.

### Question

How should I model the situation described above in my database structure?

Comment: Do the business logic in your application code, not the database.  A database is for storage of data and only simple 'models'.

Comment: @RickJames, I agree that the business logic should be handled in the application but there is still a need to store the business rules for the discounts.  I think that's what the OP was asking.

Comment: That particular discount seems rather complex -- since it involves 3 products.  Can you list the rules with pencil and paper in tabular format?  If so, then you have the contents of the necessary table.

Comment: Is it always `one`, `two`, and `three`?  Or maybe other products?  Is it always buy 2 (not 1, not 6) different things to get a discount on exactly 1 other product?  (I suspect that the specification is incomplete, so I don't want to guess at an answer.)

Comment: I have solved this by creating a table for the disscount and two extra tables one for indicator products and one for objective products, additionally if the disscount is for a set of exclusive clients i created another table for clients that can make use of the disscount.